# What do I use for the Path to the Craft folder?

Tags: install, installation

I want to place my Craft folder above the root.   But, this is for an add-on site that sits within the public_html folder of the main site.

So, the index.php file sits here...

```
../public_html/add-onsite-folder/public/index.php
```

The Craft folder sits just above the `/public_html` folder of the main site.

So, how - specifically - do I set the `$craftPath`?   It's not the default `'../craft';` and I have tried numerous variations.

I am not installing locally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will definitely want to put it above the root even if it's an add-on site, in which case the proper setup would be `'../../../../craft'` but this would generate a conflict with the main site craft install since there would be two folders with the same name above `/public_html`, so you could rename the add-on site craft folder to `craftaddon` and than the path would be `'../../../../craftaddon'`.

In case there's a really good reason for leaving it below the root, you would just use `'../../../craft'` but that does come with security risks that are pretty much not worth taking.

Comment: 1. The main site is not a Craft site. So, there is no conflict.  2. Everything on the Craft Installation page says "We recommend that you upload the folder above your web root if possible" ...so I am confused

Comment: Well, i made a mistake in my answer, meant above and wrote below ( will edit my answer to reflect that). But to sum it up the craft folder should not be inside `public_html` or one of its inner folders.

Comment: Okay, that is cool.  I got it to work using your recommendation above.  I was spelling things out from L to R, instead of R to L and using `../` to represent each level.  Noob mistake no doubt.